# Send data in Ajax response

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

hey I am trying to populate one select dropdown on the basis of another one using ajax. I have one select populated with portfolios and the 2nd one is empty. when I select an option from the 1st select box. I call an ajax function in which I send the selected portfolio id, In the ajax method I find the groups for the selected id, how can I populate the 2nd select with the groups I found. My code is

The form which contains two selects

```
<form name="portfolios" action="{{ path('v2_pm_portfolio_switch') }}" method="post" >
        <select id="portfolios" name="portfolio" style="width: 200px; height:25px;">
            <option selected="selected" value="default">Select Portfolio</option>
            {% for portfolio in portfolios %}
                <option get-groups="{{ path('v2_pm_patents_getgroups') }}" value={{ portfolio.id }}>{{ portfolio.portfolioName }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select><br/><br/>
        <select id="portfolio-groups" name="portfolio-groups" style="width: 200px; height:25px;">
            <option selected="selected" value="default">Select Portfolio Group</option>
        </select><br/>
</form>
```

The JS

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#portfolios').change(function() {
            var id = $("#portfolios").val();
            var url = $('option:selected', this).attr("get-groups");
            var data = {PID:id};
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                url:url,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    //want to populate the 2nd select box here
                }
            });
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Controller method where I find the groups for the selected portfolio

```
public function getgroupsAction(Request $request){
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

        $id = $request->get("PID");
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $portfolio_groups = $em->getRepository('MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:PmPatentgroups')
        ->getpatentgroups($id);
        return $portfolio_groups;
    }
}
```

Any idea how can i send the portfolio groups and populate the 2nd select

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you familiar with XML?  If you format your request return as XML, Javascript can easily parse it, and use the information to populate your page.

Comment: No I am not too much familiar with XML...

Comment: Alright, well, it's a very useful tool, and very easy to learn.  If you know HTML, you already know XML, you just don't know it, yet.  This [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/) should help you get started.  XML is just a way to organize data, you can take it wherever you want from there.  Most languages (including JS) have XML parsers built in, so it's easy to get the data stored in an XML fragment into your language for use.  Check out that tutorial while I fashion an answer for you.

Comment: Thank you so much I will go through it :)

Comment: Why use XML if you can use JSON and forget about handling xml with JS. Not to mention that using JSON is much more intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getJson` instead of `ajax()`;

Json (JavaScript Object Notation) , is the most easiest way to send structured data between php and javascript.

I Assuming here that the controller respond directly to the ajax query and that `$portfolio_groups` is an associative array with "id" and "name" as keys or an object with this same properties.

In your PHP controller send json data:

```
public function getgroupsAction(Request $request){
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

        $id = $request->get("PID");
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $portfolio_groups = $em->getRepository('MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:PmPatentgroups')
        ->getpatentgroups($id);
        echo json_encode($portfolio_groups);
    }
}
```

Then use getJson to retrieve data and iterate over it :

```
$.getJSON(url, data, function(result) {
    var options = $("#portfolio-groups");
    $.each(result, function(item) {
        options.append($("<option />").val(item.id).text(item.name));
    });
});
```

Have a look to the [getjson documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for more detail about it

Comment: How I will send the id of the selected portfolio to my controller then?

Comment: It gives the response like this assume there is only one group for the selected portfolio...[{"id":"09c0d4b2-ac25-11e1-96a5-9787dec335c2","name":"Group 2","description":"No Description Provided for this Group","order":500000,"is_deleted":false}]

But it gives me an error about the first select box and says Variable portfolio does not exists....

Comment: I have updated my answer to fit your object structure. The error you get , probably come from previous JS code , i don't use any 'portfolio' variable in my example

Comment: There is no previous JS the only JS I execute is this one :( but why portfolio variable is not visible

Comment: Now when I change the value in 1st select box it creates options in the 2nd select but empty options neither id nor the name of the options are visible?

Comment: and I added return new Response(); at the end of my ajax call... because it was giving the error that the controller must return a response (null given)

Comment: in the each loop comment option.append and add console.log(item); and start debugging with your browser dev tool (firebug, etc ...)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this XML [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/) (someone out there is going to flame me for linking to w3schools) it's a good start.

AJAX requests are, in VERY broad terms, calls which make a browser open a window that only it can see (not the user).  A request is made to the server, the server returns a page, the script that made the request can view that page.  This means that anything which can be expressed in text can be transmitted via AJAX, including XML (for which the X in AJAX stands for).

How is this helpful?  Consider, if you are trying to populate a drop down list, you need to return a list of items to populate it with.  You COULD make an ajax call to a page `http://www.mysite.com/mypage.php?d=select1` (if you are unfamiliar with GET and POST requests, or are a little in the dark regarding the more utilitarian aspects of AJAX, another full tutorial is available [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)) and have it return a list of items as follows:

```
item1
item2
item3
...
```

And scan the text for line breaks.  While this certainly would work for most cases, it's not ideal, and certainly won't be useful in all other cases where AJAX may be used.  Instead consider formatting the return in your PHP (.NET, ASP, whatever) in XML:

```
<drop>
    <item>item1</item>
    <item>item2</item>
    <item>item3</item>
</drop>
```

And use Javascripts built in parser (outlined [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp)) to grab the data.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to use the $.load() function.
To do this, your `getgroupsAction` should return the options html.

The JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#portfolios').change(function() {
            var id = $("#portfolios").val();
            var url = $('option:selected', this).attr("get-groups");
            var data = {PID:id};

            // Perhaps you want your select to show "Loading" while loading the data?
            $('#portfolio-groups').html('<option selected="selected" value="default">Loading...</option>');

            $('#portfolio-groups').load(url, data);
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

I don't know how `$portfolio_groups` stores the data, but let's say you'd do something like this in your response:

```
<?php foreach($portfolio_groups as $p) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $p->value ?>"><?php echo $p->name ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

This way, the select will be filled with the options outputted by `getgroupsAction`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to return json string from your controller and then process it in the 'success' call of the $.ajax.

Lets assume, that your $portfolio_groups variable is an array:

`$portfolio_groups = array('1'=>'Portfolio 1', '2' => 'Portfolio 2');`

then you can return it from controller as json string like this:

`echo json_encode($portfolio_groups);`

Then in your jQuery ajax call you can catch this string in the response (the 'success' setting of the $.ajax). Don't forget to add setting dataType: 'json'

Roughly, your $.ajax call will look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    url:url,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json', // don't forget to add this setting
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(id, title){
            var node = $('<option>').attr('value', id).html(title);

            // this will simply add options to the existing list of options
            // you might need to clear this list before adding new options
            $('#portfolio-groups').append(node);
        });
    }
});
```

Of course, you will also need to add the checks if the data is not empty, etc.

Comment: and what if the $portfolio_groups is an object not an array ?

Comment: Than you can simply create an array that represents properties of this object. E.g., object from the class myclass { $prop1 = 1, $prop2 = 2 }  can be represented as array('prop1'=>1,'prop2'=>2)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the function *getgroupsAction* stays in a flat php controller ( not inside a class ) you should tell the server to execute the function

so at the end of file being called by ajax you should barely call the function first ( probably you did it! )

For your patents group result set, you can generate the select by php or by javascript

In first case you should do this:

```
//php
  $options = getgroupsAction($_REQUEST);
  $return = "<select name =\"name\" id=\"id\"><option value=\"\"></option>";
 foreach( $options as $option){
       $return.= "<option value=\"$option\">$option</option>";
 }
 $return .= "</select>";
  echo $return;
```

Then in Javascript:
     // javascript

```
  var data = {PID:id};
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            url:url,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                //inside data you have the select html code so just:
               $('#divWhereToappend').append(data);
            },
    error: function(data) {
                //ALWAYS print the error string when it returns error for a more easily debug
         alert(data.responseText);
            }
        });
```